# object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc returning empty data

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
'images_jpg_splitted/train/img',
'images_jpg_splitted/train/xml',
['bat']
)

val_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(
'images_jpg_splitted/test/img',
'images_jpg_splitted/test/xml',
['bat']
)

I am trying to detect bat from images. I have labeled the data using labelImg.
While trying to load the data from tflite_model_maker, object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc returns empty data. I have tried not splitting the image and XML file and it still did not work.

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet ?

Comment: Yes. I will try to answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the image file. The file supported was only jpeg but although the extension was a jpeg, it was not recognizing the images as jpeg maybe because it was a png file and the extension was renamed. So, I used PIL to convert them to jpeg.

```
import PIL.Image
import glob
import os

if not "converted" in os.listdir():
    os.mkdir("converted")

lst_imgs = [i for i in glob.glob("*.jpeg")]
print(lst_imgs)
for i in lst_imgs:
    img = PIL.Image.open(i)
    img = img.convert("RGB")
    img.save("converted\\"+i, "JPEG")


print("Done.")
os.startfile("converted")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because I was specifying the path to my annotations using ~. Starting my path with /home/myuser fixed this for me.

Answer (score -2):

could you please write the code in below style?

`dataloader = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(image_dir, annotations_dir, label_map={1: "person", 2: "notperson"})`

It may be a syntax issue.

Comment: Tried that and it is still the same